# Eclipse CDTでワンクリックで編集中のソースをビルド、実行することはできますか？

Tags: c, eclipse

私は現在C言語の勉強をしていて、高機能なIDEを使いたいと思いEclipseをインストールしました。
1つのプロジェクト内で`hoge.c`と`hogehoge.c`を作成しビルドを押すとコンソールに`Build Finished`とは表示されるのですがexeファイルが生成されません。
どうにかできないか調べてみると`hogehoge.c`を`Properties`→`C/C++ Build`→`Exclude resource from build`にチェックを入れてビルド対象から外すと`hoge.c`が正常にビルドされ実行できるようになることがわかったのですがこの方法は面倒です。
ワンクリックで編集中のソースをビルド、実行したいのですがどうすればいいですか？

環境
・Windows 10
・Eclipse Cpp Oxygen
・GCC 6.3.0(Cygwin)

追記
`> gcc hoge.c -o hello.exe && hello.exe`
をボタンをクリックするだけで実行するようにしたいです

Comment: プロジェクトにおいてhoge.cとhogehoge.cに依存関係はあるのでしょうか。デフォルトではプロジェクトフォルダ以下にあるソースがすべてビルドに必要なファイルと判断されていると思うので、hogehoge.cがhoge.cに関係しないのであれば、既に試された除外指定を行うか、別のフォルダに移動する必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick コメントありがとうございます。やはりその方法しかないのでしょうか…